# Wait for img.onload inside a synchronious function

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload

I have a situation where I need to wait for a img.onload function to resize a picture.
The img.onload function is located within a synchronious function, which can not be async.
I need to wait for the img.onload before I can continue inside the synchronious function.

Does anyone have an idea on how to realize it?

Example:

```
  function test(img) {
    const img =  new Image();

    img.onload = function () {
       //Here needs something to happen, set a variable
       x = value;
    };

    //After the img.onload I need to access this here
    console.log(x);
  }
```

This is what I have so far.
I know that img.onload will be executed later and console.log(x) is fired before that, but it needs to be afterwards. I can sadly not just move it into img.onload because this function test is used to upload and wont work otherwise.

Appreciating any tips.

EDIT:

Actual code I am using to resize an image before uploading.
Uploading takes place in the test function, after this code:

```
img.onload = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    const [newWidth, newHeight] = calculateSize(img, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    canvas.style = "display: none";
    canvas.toBlob(
        (blob) => {
            // Handle the compressed image. es. upload or save in local state
            let file_small = new File([blob], name,{type:"image/jpeg", lastModified:new Date().getTime()});
            let container = new DataTransfer();
            container.items.add(file_small);
            ajaxData.set('upload', container.files[0]);
            console.log("END of the onload");
                },
            MIME_TYPE,
            QUALITY
        );
};
```

Comment: can you use Promises inside Image function?

Comment: I think so, but how would you go about it?

Comment: can you please provide Image function code? so i can give you a solution

Comment: I edited the code which is inside my onload!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the example, but you can update as you want.

```js
async function test() {
  const myImage = new Image(100, 200);
  myImage.src = 'https://images.kiwi.com/airlines/128x128/0B.png';
  document.body.appendChild(myImage);
  await callFunction(myImage);
  console.log('called second');
}

function callFunction(img) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    img.onload = () => {
        //here you all code goes
        console.log('called first');
        resolve(true)
    }
  })
}

test()
```

please vote answer as a useful if this is a solution, thank you in advance.